# Can't find bin of python library installed by pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

I try to install https://github.com/architv/soccer-cli by pip

After that I try add to PATH (used MacOS Sierra 10.12.5). But I can't find where it installed by pip on my mac. I find in [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/get-football-soccer-scores-fixtures-and.html) for Ubuntu

```
echo "PATH=\"\$HOME/.local/bin:\$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

It's don't work for MacOS. Any suggesions?

Comment: Should still be in /usr/local/bin/         
The package itself could be in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: @Uvar i already have /usr/local/bin in PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin/ . But when i try call $ soccer --help    -bash: soccer: command not found

Comment: pip show soccer-cli   ---- the output of that command should tell you relevant info

Comment: @Uvar , in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ i found only Extras.pth and README

Comment: Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soccer_cli-0.1.0.0-py2.7.egg

Comment: @Uvar but i must add path to bin file to $PATH, because bash can't find command

Comment: https://github.com/architv/soccer-cli/issues/97 I'll reference. And if pip installs correctly, the relevant .py files should be added to your bin. There is something else at play here.